# Ignore Lorem Ipsum text in a file Ruby

Tags: ruby, include

I have a .txt file that has last name, first name on one line and on every other line I have Lorem Ipsum text. I need to detect the Lorem Ipsum in every other line and skip it.

example txt.file

```
Spade, Kate
Voluptatem ipsam et at.
Vuitton, Louis
Facere et necessitatibus animi.
Bucks, Star
Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
Cage, Nicholas
Unde voluptas sit fugit.
Brown, James
Maiores ab officia sed.
```

expected output:

```
#Spade, Kate
#Vuitton, Louis
#Bucks, Star
#Cage, Nicholas
#Brown, James
```

Comment: Do you just want to skip every other line or actually detect "lorem ipsum" as the title implies?

Comment: Whenever you give an example *always* show the desired result (i.e., return value). Please edit.

Comment: Okay I edited the question a bit. Let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: When you say _"I need to detect the Lorem Ipsum in every other line and skip it"_ – what does _"detect the Lorem Ipsum"_ mean? Why not just skip every other line?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to skip every second line you can do something like this:

```
File.open("text.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line.with_index do |line, i|
    next unless i.even?
    puts line
  end
end

#Spade, Kate
#Vuitton, Louis
#Bucks, Star
#Cage, Nicholas
#Brown, James
```

Now I'm not really good with regexp, but you could also do something like this to process only the lines that are two words, both starting with a capital letter separated by a comma and space (basically first name and last name):

```
File.open("text.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    next unless line =~ /[A-Z][a-z]+, [A-Z][a-z]+/
    puts line
  end
end

#Spade, Kate
#Vuitton, Louis
#Bucks, Star
#Cage, Nicholas
#Brown, James
```

You could also load the full Lorem Ipsum text from a file like this:

```
lorem = File.open("lorem.txt", "r").map(&:chomp).join(" ")
```

And then check each line if it's contained in the Lorem Ipsum text:

```
File.open("text.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    next if lorem.include?(line[0...-1]) #removing the last character because you seem to have a dot at the end even though in the lorem text there's no dot on these positions.
    puts line
  end
end

#Spade, Kate
#Vuitton, Louis
#Bucks, Star
#Cage, Nicholas
#Brown, James
```

Now depending on what you want to do with the data you can replace the `puts line` line with something else.

Comment: `i % 2 == 0` could also be written as `i.even?`

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I tried to make a version that checks the full Lorem Ipsum text for each line in the file that OP provided and skips the line if it's included in the Lorem text, but I couldn't find the full text. Every version I found didn't contain the second sentence from OP's question.

Comment: I changed the Lorem Ipsum text

Comment: @downwiththe.click These solutions still produce the expected output :)

Comment: @downwiththe.click I added a third solution, keep in mind the Lorem Ipsum lines from the example have to be contained in the Lorem Ipsum text :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to method chain and I think my method is getting too large! Thank you so much. I'm a bit confused I'm a new coder. The problem is i will be tested against a file that may have different Lorem text so I'm not sure whats the best way to go about this

Comment: @downwiththe.click Why can't you use my first solution, which skips every second line? It's the most simple approach

Comment: I started there and I got an error that says: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Comment: @downwiththe.click On which line of code did you get the error ? Can you be more specific? I tested the code and it doesn't raise and error

Answer (score 3):

Reading 2 lines and ignoring the second:

```
File.open("test.txt", "r") do |f|
  f.each_slice(2) do |odd, _even|
    puts odd
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is unclear. If you just want to skip every other line, you can do something like this:

```
File.foreach("test.txt").with_index(1) do |l, i|
  next if i.even?
  puts l
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first create a file.

```
FName = 'temp.txt'
```

```
IO.write(FName,
<<~END
Spade, Kate
Voluptatem ipsam et at.
Vuitton, Louis
Facere et necessitatibus animi.
Bucks, Star
Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
Cage, Nicholas
Unde voluptas sit fugit.
Brown, James
Maiores ab officia sed.
END
)
  #=> 211
```

Here's one way to return every other line.

```
IO.foreach(FName).each_slice(2).map(&:first)
  #=> ["Spade, Kate\n", "Vuitton, Louis\n", "Bucks, Star\n",
  #    "Cage, Nicholas\n", "Brown, James\n"]
```

See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-write), [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-map).

Note that `foreach`, `each_slice` and `map` all return enumerators when they are not given block. We therefore obtain the following:

```
enum0 = IO.foreach(FName)
  #=> #<Enumerator: IO:foreach("temp.txt")> 
enum1 = enum0.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: IO:foreach("temp.txt")>:each_slice(2)> 
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: IO:foreach("temp.txt")>
  #     :each_slice(2)>:map> 
enum2.each(&:first)
  #=> ["Spade, Kate\n", "Vuitton, Louis\n", "Bucks, Star\n",
  #    "Cage, Nicholas\n", "Brown, James\n"]
```

Examine the return values for the calculation of `enum1` and `enum2`. It may be helpful to think of these as These could be thought of as *compound* enumerators.

Two other ways:

```
enum = [true, false].cycle
  #=> #<Enumerator: [true, false]:cycle> 
IO.foreach(FName).select { enum.next }
  #=> <as above>

keep = false
IO.foreach(FName).select { keep = !keep }
  #=> <as above>
```