# Find the Unique last names from a .txt file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unique

I need to find the unique last names from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Kent, Mackenna -- ut
    Voluptatem ipsam et at.
Marven, Gardens -- non
    Facere et necessitatibus animi.
McLaughlinn, Matt -- consequatur
    Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
Lang, August -- pariatur
    Unde voluptas sit fugit.
Brad, Nick -- et
    Maiores ab officia sed.
Adam, Levine -- error
    Repellendus alias officia amet et perspiciatis.
Learner, York -- nesciunt
    Incidunt et ut necessitatibus porro.
Ortiz, Andrew -- fuga
    Tempore eos et hic.
Lang, Bryant -- et
Laborum perferendis inventore eveniet.
```

So far I have:

```
FNAME = 'example.txt'

# maps for last name in file
def last_name_from_file(file_name)
  last_name = File.readlines(file_name).reject(&:empty?)
  last_name.map do |line|
    line.split.first
  end
end
puts last_name_from_file('example.txt')
```

but this gives me the output which includes the Lorem text and the last name.

```
#Kent
#Voluptatem
#Marven
#Facere
#McLaughlinn
#Eveniet
#Lang
#Unde
#Brad
...
```

Comment: All the odd lines are indented but the last. If they are always indented please edit the example; if they may not be indented please say so. Please .edit to show the complete desired result for the given example. Whenever you give an example please show the desired result (as a Ruby object).

Answer (score 1):

As I see lorem lines are even, so you can reject them.

```
def last_name_from_file(file_name)
  File.
    readlines(file_name).
    reject.
    with_index(1) { |_, id| id.even? }.
    map { |line| line.split(',').first }.
    uniq
end
```

> Okay how would I go about getting the first name?

You can do method like this:

```
def names(file_name)
  File.
    readlines(file_name).
    reject.
    with_index(1) { |_, id| id.even? }.
    map { |line| line.split(' --').first.split(', ') }.
    map { |ln, fn| { lastname: ln, firstname: fn } }
end
```

And now you can call it:

```
names = names('example.txt')

names
# => [{:lastname=>"Kent", :firstname=>"Mackenna"}, {:lastname=>"Marven", :firstname=>"Gardens"}, {:lastname=>"McLaughlinn", :firstname=>"Matt"}, {:lastname=>"Lang", :firstname=>"August"}, {:lastname=>"Brad", :firstname=>"Nick"}, {:lastname=>"Adam", :firstname=>"Levine"}, {:lastname=>"Learner", :firstname=>"York"}, {:lastname=>"Ortiz", :firstname=>"Andrew"}, {:lastname=>"Lang", :firstname=>"Bryant"}]

names.map { |name| name[:lastname] }
# => ["Kent", "Marven", "McLaughlinn", "Lang", "Brad", "Adam", "Learner", "Ortiz", "Lang"]

names.map { |name| name[:firstname] }
# => ["Mackenna", "Gardens", "Matt", "August", "Nick", "Levine", "York", "Andrew", "Bryant"]
```

Comment: Okay how would I go about getting the first name?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417370/9785060) from yesterday:

```
def last_name_from_file(fname)
  File.open(fname, "r").each_with_object([]).with_index do |(line, o), i|
    o << line.split(',').first if i.even?
  end.uniq
end

puts last_name_from_file('example.txt')

#Kent
#Marven
#McLaughlinn
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's create the file.

```
FName = 'temp.txt'
```

```
IO.write(FName,
<<~END
Kent, Mackenna -- ut
    Voluptatem ipsam et at.
Marven, Gardens -- non
    Facere et necessitatibus animi.
McLaughlinn, Matt -- consequatur
    Eveniet temporibus ducimus amet eaque.
Lang, August -- pariatur
    Unde voluptas sit fugit.
Brad, Nick -- et
    Maiores ab officia sed.
Adam, Levine -- error
    Repellendus alias officia amet et perspiciatis.
Learner, York -- nesciunt
    Incidunt et ut necessitatibus porro.
O'Conner-Bolonzo, Andrew -- fuga
    Tempore eos et hic.
Lang, Bryant -- et
Laborum perferendis inventore eveniet.
END
)
  #=> 539
```

We can extract the unique last names by making a single pass through the file, reading line-by-line; there is no need to slurp the file into an array.

```
require 'set'

IO.foreach(FName).each_with_object(Set.new) do |line,set|
   last_name = line[/\A[\p{Alpha}'-]+(?=,)/]
   set << last_name unless last_name.nil?
end.to_a
  #=> ["Kent", "Marven", "McLaughlinn", "Lang", "Brad", "Adam", "Learner",
  #    "O'Conner-Bolonzo"]
```

See [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach), [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), [Set::new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new), [Set#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-to_a) and [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

Note that, when not given a block, `IO::foreach` returns an enumerator, and therefore can be chained, here to `Enumerable#each_with_object`.

The regular expression used by `String#[]` reads, "match one or more (`+`) characters at the beginning of the string (`\A`) that are letters, apostrophes or hyphens, immediately followed by a comma."